# android in app update page backpressed question

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update

We have created an Android in-app update feature.
We are also in the process of testing.

However, on the Google-provided in-app update screen, click Back on the user's device to exit the screen. (Download was successful)
Is there a way to keep it from leaving this screen?

The back function used the onBackPressuredDispatcher, not the onBackPressured.

OnBackPressedCallback (true) state by default.
And I'm not sure what to do when I'm working on an update.